# How to compare date with a date range

Tags: java, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to calculate Total of Quantity and GROUP BY CarID but am currently unable to do this.

In my database have some tables: TBL_CAR_TX, TBL_CAR, TBL_PERSON

```
table: TBL_CAR_TX
------------------
select * from TBL_CAR_TX
where TranDate >= '2011-06-09' and Trandate <= '2011-06-20'

    TranID, AccID, CarID, TranDate, Type, Quantity, .....
    --------------------------------------------------------
    0      2563    BMW    2011-06-09   H    -15 (1)
    1      2563    BMW    2011-06-20   R     15
    2      2563    BMW    2011-06-20   H     20
    3      0055    TOY    2011-06-12   H    -10 (2)
    4      0055    TOY    2011-06-20   R     10

...
```

(H): Hold, (R): Release 
if we change the condition of the WHERE stmt:

```
select * from TBL_CAR_TX where TranDate >= '2011-06-10' and Trandate <= '2011-06-19'
```

(these date, I get them from outside) 
==> all of the records disappear ==> I can't calculate because the data doesn't display.

Look at the table TBL_CAR_TX, we can see that a person borrow car 'BMW' from '2011-06-09' and until '2011-06-20' he returned it. So If I do in SQL Server 2008, how can I keep the record (1) & (2) in the range date from '2011-06-10' to '2011-06-19' to calculate. If can not, how can I do it in java programming ? Any suggest.

```
table TBL_CAR:

    MarketID, CarID, Name, Size, ...
    ---------------------------
    GER       BMW    ....
    JPA       TOY    ....

Table TBL_PERSON:

    AccID, Name, Age, DOB, ...
    -------------------------
    2563   Robert
    0055   Mike
```

Thanks you very much for your help

Comment: You need to search for date comparison functions (I guess one is called BETWEEN, but I used MSSQL once in my life, but some SQL implementations have that)

Answer (score 1):

> I want to calculate Total of Quantity and GROUP BY CarID but am currently unable to do this. 
>   So If I do in SQL Server 2008, how can I keep the record (1) & (2) in
>   the range date from '2011-06-10' to '2011-06-19' to calculate.

Just get rid of `=` from your SQL.

```
select CarID, SUM(QUANTITY) from TBL_CAR_TX where TranDate > '2011-06-09' and Trandate < '2011-06-20' GROUP BY CarID
```

or use [BETWEEN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa225976%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) SQL CLAUSE.

```
select CarID, SUM(QUANTITY) from TBL_CAR_TX where TranDate BETWEEN '2011-06-10' AND '2011-06-19' GROUP BY CarID
```

> If can not, how can I do it in java programming ?

You can definitely filter out the data in java but there is no point in doing so when SQL can do the work for you. Unless it is a massive performance penalty, it is almost always worth doing the processing like this in SQL.

Comment: wooo. I guessed the between ;) AFAIK the BETWEEN version should optimize better.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I already try them but no record display

Comment: @Bryan - Did you paste the correct data? Also do you get a SQL error? It could be that TranDate is not defined as a DATE field in your table. Could you check the table schema?

Comment: @naugtur - Good guess on between. Unless we can see how many pages the 2 sql fetches it's hard to tell which one is better optimized. I know in case of DB2 the > and < tends to get fetch less pages and less CPU consuming.

Comment: @bryan - it works. You must be giving dates in an incorrect format or something

Comment: @Bryan - SQL can do it fine. It has been done for decades. You are doing something wrong. Let's figure that out first. :-). So how are you running the SQL? Secondly, do you see any error messages?

Comment: I think SQL can not do it. I think to the solution do it in Java, pass the parameter date inside and compare it with TranDate. For example: <br> if mydate before 09/06 then Quantity = 0, if mydate equal 09/06 then Quantity = -15, if mydate after 09/06 and before 20/06 then Quantity = -15 <br> and ...., but currently I'm not sure with my solutions, and I also don't know how to calculate it correct with Hold and Release (and maybe seperate 2 funtions of Hold and Release ???)

Comment: @Bryan - do you want to sum only when it's on H ? Again SQL is the way to go here. Don't get side tracked :)

Comment: I already try those SQL above but no record display: select * from TBL_CAR_TX where TranDate > '2011-06-09' and Trandate < '2011-06-20' or use BETWEEN stmt.

Comment: Hi CoolBeans, I must calculate SUM for both Hold and Release when I pass date inside sql stmt

Comment: In my SQL Server 2008, I saw in properties for TranDate is Date type, and run those SQL don't display any error

Comment: @Bryan - then your SQL is correct. Either you are passing wrong dates or getting SQL exceptions. Have you tried running the SQL in a SQL editor outside of your application? Does it return data then?

Comment: Yes, SQL correclty, I was using SQL 2008 Editor, no exceptions displayed, no more data display if I use this sql: select * from TBL_CAR_TX where TranDate > '2011-06-10' and Trandate < '2011-06-19'. It only display with the date range of TranDate >= '2011-06-09' and Trandate <= '2011-06-20'

Comment: @Bryan - you are probably showing the wrong data in the post. Either you are querying with an alias (ie. Bryan.TBL_CAR_TX) or something is different.